# limit scroll function to a single page

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a javascript function that does this

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 52) {
    do something
  } else {
    do something
  }
});
```

But I want this function to fire only for a certain page and not entire website. Is there a way I can add a page id to this? Something like this?

```
 document.addEventListener('scroll', "#pageID", function (event) {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 52) {
        do something
      } else {
        do something
      }
    });
```

Comment: Checking for page url works ?

Comment: Why don't you just add this script to the page that needs it?

Answer (score 0):

So there are two ways:

First way is to check the url then fire the function:

```
if (window.location.pathname == "/path/to/PageName.html") {

  document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 52) {
    do something
  } else {
    do something
  }
  });

}
```

Second would be to add the jquery snippet to only page that need this functionality.

Comment: Thank you. but wouldn't there be another way to specify the container div ID?

Comment: `document` contains the DOM; there is no container div for `document`.  If you were watching for scroll events on a DOM node instead of on the window, then you could use its ID, sure.